# What is the fastest way of calculate cosine similarity between rows of two same shape matrices

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, linear-algebra, cosine-similarity

For example, I have two 2D array as follow:

```
X = array([[4, 4, 4, 2],
   [3, 1, 2, 2],
   [1, 3, 3, 3],
   [1, 3, 1, 2]])
Y = array([[2, 1, 1, 4],
   [2, 1, 1, 1],
   [4, 1, 4, 4],
   [4, 2, 3, 4]])
```

I want to calculate cosine simarity between rows of X and Y. such as

```
def cos(feats1, feats2):
    """
    Computing cosine distance
    For similarity
    """
    cos = np.dot(feats1, feats2) / (np.linalg.norm(feats1) * np.linalg.norm(feats2))
    return cos

for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    print(cos(a[i,:],b[i,:]))
```

Right now, I am using for loop to calculate cos distance between vectors. But the size of X and Y is like (1200000000, 512), it takes realy long time to calculate just using for loop.

My question is how i can utilize the power of algebra and numpy to speed up this process.

Or any other method that can perform this calculation more efficient.

Thanks

Comment: If those are 32-bit integers, that array occupies 2.4TB.  You can't really be storing that in memory.

Comment: You could use `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` which is quite fast, you can convert to using similarity = 1 - distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible in one single line: the trick is to just specify the axis over which perform the norm and the dot product.

```
X = np.random.randn(3,2)
Y = np.random.randn(3,2)
(X * Y).sum(axis=1) / np.linalg.norm(X, axis=1) / np.linalg.norm(Y, axis=1)
```

The first part, `(X * Y).sum(axis=1)` takes care of computing the dot product. `axis=1` specify that we perform the dot product over the columns, i.e. get a result for each row (the datapoints).

The second part simply computes the norm of each vector, with the same method.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use `numpy`, make good use of broadcasting:

```
>>> def cos(x, y):
...     return (x * y).sum(axis=1) / (np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1) * np.linalg.norm(y, axis=1))
...
>>> X = np.array([[4, 4, 4, 2],
...    [3, 1, 2, 2],
...    [1, 3, 3, 3],
...    [1, 3, 1, 2]])
>>> Y = np.array([[2, 1, 1, 4],
...    [2, 1, 1, 1],
...    [4, 1, 4, 4],
...    [4, 2, 3, 4]])
>>> cos(X, Y)
array([0.70957488, 0.97995789, 0.83692133, 0.80829038])
```